# Problem when splitting an item from array list into a string array

Tags: java, android, arrays, split

Hello I have an array list that consists of numbers but are strings.

Like this: `["1.1",1.2]`. The problem is that I am running into that I am using a for function to split an item of the array list into a string array.

For example if I have array list: `["1.1","1.2"]` I would

```
String[] string_array= array_list.get(0).split("\\.");
```

That should be working fine, but the problem that I am facing is that it would create a weird string array like `[Ljava.lang.String;@ccac396` .

I am not really sure what causes this problem as I used split and array string before and none of this happened.

**Note:** I am splitting on `.` ,but since `.` is a regex I have to use `\\.` which should split on `.`.

Here is the part of the code that is causing the problem:

```
for (int i = 0; i < array_list.size(); i++) {
        String[] splitted_on_for_for_reverse;
        splitted_on_for_for_reverse = array_list.get(i).split("\\.");
        array_list.remove(i);
        String string_to_add = splitted_on_for_for_reverse[1].concat(".").concat(splitted_on_for_for_reverse[0]);
        array_list.add(string_to_add);
    }
```

I know the problem is not happening from the array list as I have tested it with logs and its fine. the problem is with the string array but I dont know what to do. Any help is appreciated and thanks in advance

Comment: `[Ljava.lang.String;@ccac396` I think you are logging the srray. That is not the way to see it's content. Check it in debugger

Comment: String[] string_array= array_list.get(0).split("\."); this does not return a "weird" string array. Maybe you are trying to print it in a weird way.

Comment: String.split method return an array. of the split items. Also do not remove the items while you iterate them.

Comment: Ok thanks guys it turns it I was logging the array string instead of logging each time of the array separate. Silly Mistake. Thanks everyone

Comment: hey guys can you post your comment as an answer so I can mark it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[Ljava.lang.String;@ccac396` is not a the string itself, but its location or the location of the string array, respectively. I think you are you printing the whole `String[]` array, which results in the *weird* output. Java uses its default `toString()` method, which often just returns the objects position/reference.

Try to iterate over this array and print each `String` separately.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and in fact this is what I were doing. I accepted your answer. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 1):

To print a string array you must use

```
Arrays.toString(string_array);
```